# ESP8266 GETTING 302 FOUND

Tags: php, html

I am trying to read a webpage content using ESP8266, instead of web content I am getting 302 found. please help. (when value of parameter u=12 the page will be displaying "ready12") not getting it.

> AT+CIPSTART="TCP","www.webiotplatform.in",80
>   AT+CIPSTART="TCP","www.webiotplatform.in",80 CONNECT
>
> OK AT+CIPSEND=64 AT+CIPSEND=64
>
> OK
>
> > GET / systemstate.php?u=12 HTTP/1.1 Host: webiotplatform.in
>
> Recv 64 bytes
>
> SEND OK
>
> +IPD,414:HTTP/1.1 302 Found Date: Fri, 28 Apr 2017 12:37:01 GMT Server: Apache Location: http://www.webiotplatform.in/ Content-Length:
>   213 Connection: close Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
>
> 302 Found
>
> ## Found
>
> The document
>   has moved [here](http://www.webiotplatform.in/).